# Change view of detail pane on UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an app to try and learn a bit more about the cocoa touch framework and am starting to use the `UISplitViewController`. From what I have learned so far, this has a property called `viewControllers` that is an array containing the master and detail view controllers for the app.

What I am trying to set up is a folder navigation system in the `masterVC`, then when a specific file is selected, it is opened in the `detailVC`. I have got the folder navigation working and can pass the details of the files between the two view controllers.

My problem is that there are several types of files that require different views to display them correctly.

For example a jpeg image will have an image viewer, whereas an html document will have a web view and a txt document will require a text editor view.

What is the best way to change the view controller of the detail pane?

Am I better to have a single View controller and swap different views in and out depending on the file type? Or is there a way to completely remove the viewcontroller and add the appropriate one in its place?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think you should use multiple view controllers. There's bound to be a lot of logic in each of these individual view controllers you mentioned that should be properly contained within its own view controller.

As for displaying the appropriate view controller, you can easily add a `view` of a `UIViewController` to any `UIViewController`s view, by doing: `[self.view addSubview:myTextEditorVC.view]`. So in other words, your `detailVC` could handle the logic of knowing which type of `UIViewController` it needs to display, instantiate that `UIViewController`, and display its `view` within the `detailVC`'s `view`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks donkim, have a better grasp of the logic behind doing this now. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be swapping out different view controllers. In Xcode 6, you can use a "Show Detail" segue from the master to point to a different navigation controller that contains your different detail view.

[Here's an quick example.](https://github.com/dstarsboy/TMMultiDetailReplaceSegue)